# Does an audio queue callback function have to be a C style function? Or can it be an objective C style method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, core-audio, audioqueueservices

Does an audio queue callback function have to be a C style function? Or can it be an objective C style method?

Answer (score 7):

Depends entirely on the API;  if the API calls for a function, block or method, that is what you must use.

As long as the callback function type is something like:

```
void (*hollabackman)(AudioGunk*foo, void*context);
```

And the API for setting up the callback is something like:

```
setCallback(hollabackman func, void *context);
```

Then you can:

```
- myMethod
{
    setCallback(&myCallbackFunc, (void *)self);
}

- (void) hollaedBack: (AudioGunk*) aGunk
{
.....
}
```

Then:

```
void myCallbackFunc(AudioGunk *foo, void *context)
{
    MyClass *self = (MyClass *) context;
    [self hollaedBack: foo];
}
```

I would suggest that you `retain` self when setting up the callback and only balance it with a `release` when you tear down the callback.

Answer (score 1):

CoreAudio (including AudioQueueServices) does not have an ObjectiveC interface - pure C is the answer for directly interfacing with CoreAudio.

You could however create some wrapping C-functions calling a singleton ObjectiveC object method.